# Inverse DFT - Matlab vs OpenCv

Tags: matlab, opencv, fft

I'm trying to convert some Matlab code to OpenCv and have problems with inverse FFT. Codes in MATLAB and OpenCV gives different results.

In MATLAB:

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6;  7 8 9; 10 11 12]; %simplest matrix I can think of
mask = [0 1 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 1 0 0]';

F = fft(A,[],1);
F(~mask) = 0;
real(ifft(F,[],1))
ans =
-1.5000  -1.5000  -1.5000
-1.5000  -1.5000  -1.5000
1.5000   1.5000   1.5000
1.5000   1.5000   1.5000
```

OpenCV:

```
Mat A = (Mat_<float>(4,3) <<  1,2,3,
                            4,5,6,
                            7,8,9,
                            10,11,12);

transpose(A,A); //transpositions to make DFT on columns like in MATLAB
Mat transformed;
dft(A,transformed,DFT_ROWS|DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);  // Applying DFT
Mat mask = (Mat_<float>(4,3) << 0,0,0,
                            1,1,1,
                            0,0,0,
                            0,0,0);
transpose(transformed,transformed);
vector<Mat> transformed_splitted;
split(transformed, transformed_splitted);
transformed_splitted[0] = transformed_splitted[0].mul(mask);
transformed_splitted[1] = transformed_splitted[1].mul(mask);
merge(transformed_splitted,transformed);
transpose(transformed,transformed);
idft(transformed,transformed,DFT_ROWS|DFT_REAL_OUTPUT|DFT_SCALE);
transpose(transformed,transformed);
cout << transformed;

output:
[-3 -3 -3 ;
-3 -3 -3 ;
3 3 3 ;
3 3 3 ]
```

It seems to me, that there is something wrong with scaling. Funny thing is that for matrix 5x3 results from both codes are the same. For 8x3 additionaly some results differ. How can I obtain same results from both IFFT?

This question is also asked in my edited post here:[Matlab FFT vs OpenCv DFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412794/matlab-fft-vs-opencv-dft)

Comment: Comment: This doesn't answer your questio, but the output dimensions of both MATLAB's version and OpenCV's version don't match.

Comment: It was my typing mistake. Now they look as they should.

Comment: No problem.  Yeah I deleted my answer because now I can't see anything wrong with your code.